# Mongodb aggregation $unwind then count

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is my problem : in my Mongo database, I have a collection with items like :

```
{
  'id': 1,
  'steps': [
    {
      action: 'start',
      info: 'foo'
    },
    {
      action: 'stop',
      info: 'bar'
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get the total number of steps 'start'.
I tryed to use the MongoDB aggregation framework : I use `$unwind` on `steps.action` and `$match` on `steps.action` to match 'start'.

However, I get too much data and reach the aggregation's limit :
`exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)`. I don't need the data, I just want the count, but I couldn't find how to do it (tryed with $group without success).

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want the count you can use this

```
db.test.count({"steps.action":"start"})
```

but this will not take into account if steps contain multiple steps with action `start`.

When you also need to count all steps with `start` then you need to unwind the array, make a match on steps.action and then group the results to count.

```
db.test.aggregate([{$unwind:"$steps"}, {$match:{"steps.action":"start"}},{ $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }])
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $unwind : "$steps" },
   {$match:{'steps.action':'start'}},
   {$group:{_id:null,count:{$sum:1}}}
]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

In mongodb, aggregation framework, the pipeline stages have maximum of 100MB size restriction,while the result it provide that is either a BSON file or a collection document has a maximum size of 16MB
So you can `$match` on require condition only and `$group` it so that only the required result is output that is less than 16MB.

Answer (score -3):

You may not need aggregation for this simple query. See below code.

```
for (var i = 10000; i >= 0; i--) {
    var a = {
      'id': 1,
      'steps': [
        {
          action: 'start',
          info: 'foo'
        },
        {
          action: 'stop',
          info: 'bar'
        }
      ]
    }

    a.id = i;
    var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    if (rnd == 1)
    {
        a.steps[0].action = 'none';
    }
    if (rnd == 2)
    {
        a.steps.push({ action: 'start', info: 'foo' })

    }
    db.obj.insert(a);
};
```

This code creates random number of actions. 
If you need only number of documents which contains action: 'start' then below query.

```
db.obj.count({"steps.action":"start"})
```

I get following count in my run.

```
> db.obj.count({"steps.action":"start"})
6756
```

But if you need number of {action: 'start'} in the documents then aggregation query needed. 
You unwind then match

```
db.obj.aggregate(
[
{ $unwind : "$steps"},
{$match: { "steps.action" : "start" }},
{
$group:
 {
   _id:  null
   ,count: { $sum: 1 }
 }
}
]
)
```

This outputs:

```
{ "_id" : null, "count" : 10054 }



if you get your exception again use **allowDiskUse : true** option. See [here][1].

db.obj.aggregate(
[
 ....
]
 ,
 { 
   allowDiskUse : true
 }

)
```

Comment: $unwind after $match will not produce the right count

Comment: Why? What does it matter if I filtered first or filtered second?

Comment: cause $match will not reduce the elements of the steps-array it will only find the elements that have an array element with action="start". the steps-array will contain the same elements as before.

Comment: @Jehof you are right. They give different outputs, I updated my answer. I need to think/read about it. Can you give me a reference?